# Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

These days I am learning Javascript Events while building my media playing application via Javascript events. I did not understand the condition used in this program/code I just want to clear my concept on these if else conditions in this code that how music played and paused by using this if else conditions?

```js
var jukeBox = document.querySelector('ul.player');

jukeBox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var songName = e.target.getAttribute('data-src');
  var songPlaying = document.querySelector('#player');
  if(songPlaying){
    if(songPlaying.paused){
      songPlaying.play();
      e.target.id = 'playing';
    }else{
      songPlaying.pause();
      e.target.id = 'pause';
    }
  }else{
    var audioPlayer = document.createElement('audio');
    audioPlayer.id = 'player';
    audioPlayer.src = songName;
    document.body.appendChild(audioPlayer);
    audioPlayer.play();
    e.target.id = 'playing';
  }


}, false);
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 15px/15px Helvetica;
  background: #259286;
}

ul.player {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.player li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  color: #444;
  padding: 9px 5px 10px 40px;
  background: url(images/media_btn.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: #EAE3CB;
  background-position: 9px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.player li:first-child {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top: none;
}

ul.player li:last-child {
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.player li:hover {
  background-color: #475B62;
  color: #FCF4DC;
}

ul.player li#playing {
  background: url(images/media_play_btn.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: #FCF4DC;
  color: #2176C7;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-position: 9px 4px;
}

ul.player li#paused {
  background: url(images/media_pause_btn.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-position: 9px 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="player">
      <li data-src="audio/Phoebex.mp3">Phoebex</li>
      <li data-src="audio/AmazingLee.mp3">AmazingLee</li>
      <li data-src="audio/NightKitty.mp3">Night Kitty</li>
      <li data-src="audio/EqueKenox.mp3">Eque Kenox</li>
      <li data-src="audio/Shiloah.mp3">Shiloah</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? When a click happens somewhere inside the song list, the handler will check if there's an audio element with the id 'player'. If no element is found on the page, songPlaying will be null, and hence `if (songPlaying)` is false, which will create a new audio element and add it to the page. If an audio element is already on the page, the inner if/else checks if that audio song is playing or not and does the opposite action. So clicking the list will either create/start a song, or pause/restart a song.

Answer (score 2):

A nice sample of events with JS,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Drunk</h1>
    <div id="prompt"></div>
</body>

<script src="drunk_events.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script>
    // testing
    prompt = document.getElementById('prompt');

    const drunk = new Drunk('Alice Cooper', 12);
    drunk.Drink();

    document.addEventListener("drunkMessages", e => {
        prompt.textContent = e.detail.message;
    });
</script>

</html>
```

```js
// CUSTOM EVENT - by: Alan1963
var eventArgs = {
    message: ''
};
const drunkMessagesEvent = new CustomEvent("drunkMessages", {
    detail: eventArgs
});
// CLASS
class Drunk extends Event {
    constructor(name, limit) {
        super('drunkMessages');
        this.name = name;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    Drink() {
        const name = this.name;
        const limit = this.limit;
        const task = setInterval(timingTask, 1000);
        var count = 0;

        function timingTask() {
            count++;
            if (count > limit) {
                eventArgs.message = name + ' go to sleep';
                // stop timing task
                clearInterval(task);
            } else {
                eventArgs.message = 'Drinking ' + count + ' of ' + limit;
            }
            document.dispatchEvent(drunkMessagesEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alan1963. For StackOverflow purposes, you need to complement your answer with a minimal explanation about your code.

Comment: Hi Antonio. This is a short, complete, and functional sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
var songPlaying = document.querySelector('#player');
```

will search an element with id player in your dom.

Next the `if(songPlaying)` will be true when the element exists on your dom.

simply if songPlaying exists that won't be null and so you will enter in the if statement. Instead, if the element isn't present, an undefined will be in that variable, and the else statement will be executed.